# How to calculate actual Baud Rate and its percent error?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c, baud-rate, calculation

I am using an Arduino Uno, and I need to create a program that calculates the actual baud rate and the percent error for all standard baud rate in Arduino monitor program.

Comment: It's listed in datasheets. The table is called: "Equations for Calculating Baud Rate Register Setting"

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. Please be aware that this is not a free design house or an on-demand online technical encyclopedia. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: See http://wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php

Comment: Jasmine, if you found the below answer helpful, please upvote it and/or mark it as the answer. That's a good way of thanking @EdgarBonet for his hard work. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up to understand why voting is important.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the code used by the Arduino core library to configure
the USART baud rate register: it's in
[`HardwareSerial::begin()`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L103). The general formula is

```c++
uint16_t baud_setting = (F_CPU / 4 / baud - 1) / 2;
```

but beware of the hard-coded exception. You can replicate that part of
the code in your own.

Then, look at the ATmega328P datasheet. More specifically, at section
[24.4.1. Internal Clock Generation – The Baud Rate
Generator](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf#page=227). Here you find the formula

```
BAUD = F_CPU / (8*(UBRR0 + 1))
```

assuming the `U2X0` bit has been set (again, beware of the hard-coded
exception). Combine both formulas and you get the actual baud rate.